# Use JS to show images dependant on element class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to show a certain set of logos when someone searches a product in a specific category. The logo image element is initially hidden (display none) and will have a class for a category id. The category determines what logo gets shown. My html for one logo is:

```
<li id="show-logo" style="display: none;">
    <!-- PLaytex Logo -->
    <img src="/images/logos/playtex.jpg" class="cat_1">
</li>
```

So my function should be as follows:

```
showPartnerLogos(element, cat_id);

function showPartnerLogos(element, cat_id) {
    // then show the images with that class cat_id for that element 
}
```

I havent done any code because my JS is dismal, but this function is what currently is being used to show a modal when someone searches a product:

```
$('#modal .spinner').spin('flower', 'black');

// Loop through all selected categories
$("#form_buy input[name='buy_product']:checked").each(function() {
    $('#modal').find('.cat_' + $(this).val() ).show();
});

setTimeout(function() {
    document.location.href = $(form).attr('action');
},0);
```

This function shows the logos in a modal, I want to be able to do the same except display the logo on the page.

Comment: You might want to use CSS instead. Instead of those `<img>` tags, use `<div>` elements, give them a width / height, then set their  `background-image` properties per class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
function showPartnerLogos(element, cat_id) {
// then show the images with that class cat_id for that element 
$(element + '.' + cat_id).show();
}
```

This will display all the `img` elements with the class sent in `cat_id`.

Ideally you do not require the parameter `element` to show all img tags only but the above code can be used to hide any type of element preovided you pass the tag name in parameter element

```
function showPartnerLogos(cat_id) {
// then show the images with that class cat_id for that element 
$('img.' + cat_id).show();
}
```

please let me know if this helped.

Answer (score 0):

You it would go something like this:

```
function showPartnerLogos(element, cat_id) {
    $(element+"."+cat_id).show();
}
```

This is supposed to be called like:

```
showPartnerLogos("img", "cat_1");
```

To show all image elements matching the cat_1 class. The trick is using the final matcher: "img.cat_1" for jQuery